# Installing OVS with DPDK

Tags: virtual-machine, network-interface, intel

I am trying to install OVS 2.4 with DPDK, 
Here are the steps I have followed.

1. Install DPDK as

`git clone http://dpdk.org/git/dpdk
cd dpdk
make config T=x86_64-default-linuxapp-gcc DESTDIR=dpdk-install`

Then made changes to the file as:

`CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_COMBINE_LIBS=y 
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_VHOST=y 
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_VHOST_USER=y`

set

> EXTRA_CFLAGS=”-g –Ofast”

and finally run `make`

I have followed the steps from
1. https://download.01.org/packet-processing/ONPS2.1/Intel_ONP_Release_2.1_Performance_Test_Report_Rev1.0.pdf

2. https://gist.github.com/ConradIrwin/9077440

The installation went successfully.

Then I am installing, OVS 2.4

While running the configure script I am setting the parameters as:

```
 ./configure --with-dpdk=/root/dpdk/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc CFLAGS=”-Ofast –g”
```

At this step i am getting an error as:

**`configure error cannot link with dpdk`**

This is a known issue, I can find the bugs for it at:

http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@openvswitch.org/msg16368.html
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network.openvswitch.general/9289

The solutions proposed here do not work.

Any suggestions ?

How to :

1. How can I check the current version of DPDK package
2. How to uninstall DPDK

Comment: I don't see where you mentioned which distribution you're running. Can you provide that?

Comment: Base machine is ubuntu 16.04 server. OVS is 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I check the current version of DPDK package

If you're installing from source, there is no "package" (i.e. `.deb` file). Try running the executable you built with the `--version` flag or similar. Or see if the source code has a version number. Typically, it doesn't until it's packaged.

> 2. How to uninstall DPDK

`make install` would have copied the binary to `/usr/bin/` or similar. You'd have to reference the `Makefile` to be sure (or re-run the install command and check the output). You can just delete it. Since it's not a package, there is no uninstall command.

I suspect the root of your problem is that the last `configure` command isn't being pointed at where the dpdk library actually is.